# select random rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have one table named **Mydata** as follows

```
     id        name          type
--------------------------------------------
     1         vinu            1
     2         rinu            2
     3         dilu            1
     4         raju            2
     5         manu            3
     6         saju            3
     7         ragu            3
     8         sonu            1
     9         sam             1
     10        rag             1
--------------------------------------------
```

I want to print records with alternating `type`, for example:

First row with type =1
Second row with type =2
Third row with type =3
4th row type=1
5th row type=2 and so on

Required result as follows

```
     id            name            type
   -----------------------------------------
     1              vinu            1
     2              rinu            2
     5              manu            3
     3              dilu            1
     4              raju            2
     6              saju            3
     8              sonu            1
     7              ragu            3
     9              sam             1
     10             rag             1
 ----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What did you tried? You need to put the code that you tried.

Comment: SELECT * FROM Mydata ORDER BY RAND()

Comment: I don't think he wants that query. He needs an order for the given type.

Comment: Tarun, what relation do you see between the question and your answer? :)

Comment: This is the critical question, and makes an answer so difficult because the _relation_ is not too clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(4), `type` int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`id`, `name`, `type`)
VALUES
    (1, 'vinu', 1),
    (2, 'rinu', 2),
    (3, 'dilu', 1),
    (4, 'raju', 2),
    (5, 'manu', 3),
    (6, 'saju', 3),
    (7, 'ragu', 3),
    (8, 'sonu', 1),
    (9, 'sam', 1),
    (10, 'rag', 1)
;
```

Query:

```
SELECT id, name, type FROM (

    SELECT
    t.*,
    @rn := IF(@prev_type = type, @rn + 1, 1) AS rownumber,
    @prev_type := type
    FROM
    t
    , (SELECT @rn := 0, @prev_type := NULL) var_init_subquery
    ORDER BY type

) sq
ORDER BY rownumber, type
```

Result:

```
| id | name | type |
|----|------|------|
|  1 | vinu |    1 |
|  4 | raju |    2 |
|  5 | manu |    3 |
|  9 |  sam |    1 |
|  2 | rinu |    2 |
|  7 | ragu |    3 |
|  8 | sonu |    1 |
|  6 | saju |    3 |
| 10 |  rag |    1 |
|  3 | dilu |    1 |
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75dda/12/0)

Caveat:

Don't expect this to be performant when you have lots of data. It's doing a full table scan.

Here's a [manual entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) to read when you're interested about how this variables work.

Comment: very nice answer fancyPants

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done via a raw SQL query. Extract the rows you need to display, and then sort them via your application.

Alternatively... you could write a stored procedure, but I don't recommend this. You will need a temporary table and a cursor (that transparently creates another temporary table). Too much for a query that should be executed often.

Comment: Never say never. I have a working way in my answer. I agree though, that a stored procedure with a cursor would be overkill.